# Why the exception page doesn't show details in Development environment in IDE

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a custom error page for non-development environments. While working on this custom page, I set environment to "Staging" in launchSettings.json file.  When I switched the setting back to "Development" and restarted the app, it only showed the generic error page (see following screenshot.)
[image]

I run the trace in program.cs and did see the it was using the default exception handler middleware:  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

I even existed the IDE and started again. But the detailed error page was no longer working.  **I could not figure out what caused this to happen and unable to resolved it. Please help!** (see more details in following sections)

**TESTING INFO**:

App Type:     ASP .NET6 with razor pages

IDE:          VS 2022

Dev machine:  Windows 11

Using IIS Express to view web pages

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:16950",
      "sslPort": 44324
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebProtectConnString": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7074;http://localhost:5074",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ERROR HANDLING CONFIG (in program.cs)**

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Exceptions/ErrorHandler");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, in Program.cs file of a .net 6 project, `if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())` is the default code, but in your code snippet, it's `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())`, this means when you set `Development` in the `launchSettings.json`, your application will execute this 2 lines

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseHsts();
```

And when execute `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` with an unhandled exception, the `Error.cshtml` will appear.. That's the reason you saw the page in your screenshot.

Since you want to use a custom view for non-development environments, you may need to remove `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` and write code below, this will make your app show exception message directly in development stage and show your custom view in other stages:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Exceptions/ErrorHandler");
    app.UseHsts();
}else{ //leave the else empty, then exception will show in browser directly  }
```

Comment: sorry for attaching the wrong code in my original question. that was my previous mistake and I did corrected that before asking the question. Today, I double checked current program.cs.  The if statement to check app environment is correct.  I traced the execution and it also showed correct environment in program.cs.  Unfortunately, the web page still not showing the exception details.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: please ignore my last comments.  I misunderstood your answer.  Basically, I should use "app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage" when it is in development environment.  That will show exception details.